# NetLogo: why event only occur at discrete tick?

Tags: netlogo, a-star

Simply the problem, here I have a discrete t-list correspond with coordinate x-list and y-list for each agent-person.

```
if ticks = first t-list
```

generate new person and locate them, new person only be created when the person id is not in the existed person-id list.

```
if ticks > first t-list
```

move to next location while check whether the next location is different with current location, the code is like

```
to go
  ask persons [
    ifelse ( not empty? t-list )[ 
      if ( ticks = first t-list )[
        new-locate-persons
      ]
      if ( ticks > first t-list ) [
        move-to-nextlocations
      ]   
    ]
    [ stop ]
  ]          
  tick
end
```

for the move-to-nextlocations, I ask person to move follow the move-path which is generated by an a-star-nlogo extension in GitHub the link is 
[a-star-nlogo extension by holtri](http://github.com/holtri/NetlogoAStarExt/)

the usage is

```
a-star-nlogo:a-star-search<Turtle><TurtleSet> - return:PatchList
a-star-nlogo:a-star-search<Turtle><TurtleSet><TurtleSet> - return:PatchList
```

I use above method to generate move-path and ask agent to move-to move-path

```
to move-to-nextlocations
  set dex item 1 x-list - item 0 x-list
  set dey item 1 x-list - item 0 x-list
  if ( length x-list > 2 and dex != 0 and dey != 0) [
    ask patch-at ( item 1 x-list ) ( item 1 y-list) [
      sprout-nextlocations   1 
      [set color black ]]]
    ask persons [
      let targets nextlocations
      let blocks neighbors4 with [ ( obstacle != 0 )]
       set move-path a-star-nlogo:a-star-search-with-multiple-turtle-avoidance self targets blocks
       ifelse ( not any? other turtles-on first move-path ) [ 
         move-to first move-path
         set move-path but-first move-path
       ][
         set move-path but-first move-path
         move-to last move-path
       ]
    ] 
end
```

The question is, I found the movement only occur at the discrete tick, for example the t-list is like [6 12 18 24], the new agent generate at tick 6, they don't move when ticks at 7,8,9,10,11, persons just move suddenly at tick 12,18,24 no matter with the path planning issue. I think some problem occur at go, and define movement condition part. But, I don't have any clue for that! Anyone can help me? Many many thanks!!

Comment: The first code block isn't syntactically correct.  It won't compile.  I think that what's there isn't what you have in NetLogo.  You'll need to correct it.  I can't figure out whether there might be an error in the logic that's causing the problem you're observing, since the code doesn't make sense.

Comment: I noticed it shouldn't be second if else in front of (tick = first t-list). I revised it. The problem is, when running tick comes to equal to the number of t-list, it runs quite slow, agent generate or move, when running tick comes to the tick not in the t-list, it goes very fast and no agent move in that tick

Comment: OK, the `go` routine looks OK now.  It should be calling `new-locate-persons` on the ticks in `t-list`, and also calling `move-to-nextlocations` on most ticks.  That's assuming that what's in `t-list` any time is what you expect.  (You're removing elements from `t-list` somewhere, I assume.)  Are you sure that `move-to-nextlocations` causes movement, ever?  Can you run it from the prompt and see what happens?  It might also be useful to insert `print` statements into `move-to-nextlocations` and `new-locate-persons` to make sure they're running when you think and with correct values.

Comment: thanks, Mars. It is true, After this point is located at this t-list, I will remove it, remove the historic point from the list. I revised the move-to-nextlocation part, it can run now. I will see if I can upload the running interface later. I have an idea of how to solving this problem

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, I revised the move-to-nextlocation part, it now looks like:

```
to generate-nextlocation
  ask patch-at ( item 1 x-list ) ( item 1 y-list) [ sprout-nextlocations 1  [set color black ]]
end 

to move-to-nextlocation
let targets nextlocations

set move-path a-star-nlogo:a-star-search-with-multiple-turtle-avoidance  self targets walls
 if ( empty? move-path )[
 show "no way out"]
 while [ not empty? move-path ][
 let next-step first move-path
 set move-path but-first move-path
 move-to next-step
 pd
] 
end
```

[image: running interface]

But it still only move on the ticks in the t-list, not related to the speed setting. So I am thinking the method of solving it could be,

Since the planning path return to a Pathlist of (pxcor, pycor), I will print the pathlist of each person out and generate a new fill. Then fill the missed ticks in the t-list, read this file, re-locate them and remove the historic location from list. if I define the tick interval small enough, it may be looks more smoothly.

It is not a smart method, if anyone has better solution, please share with us! Thanks a lot!

Comment: outou, this looks like it should be an edit to the original question, or else a new question.  (I'm glad that my other comment was helpful.)